# Convert SVG path to polygon with specific number of points python

Tags: python, svg, polygon, shapes, shapely

I want to replicate the effects shown in this [Link](http://phrogz.net/svg/convert_path_to_polygon.xhtml) of iteratively generating polygons with an increasing number of points from an svg path.

I currently managed to convert the svg path to a polygon, using [svgpath2mpl](https://github.com/nvictus/svgpath2mpl)'s parse_path and to_polygons functions, then converting them to a [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) polygons. However with this approach it generates a polygon containing all the points on the path. Is there a way to sample the polygon/path to get different accuracy of polygons? This can be done before or after the conversion to polygon.

Here is what I currently have:

```
from svgpath2mpl import parse_path
mpl_path = parse_path('M12.302 798.100 c0.300 ...')
coordinates = mpl_path.to_polygons()

from shapely.geometry import Polygon
poly = Polygon(coordinates[0])
```

I also generated matplotlibs plots before and after converting using shapely and they give [identical results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJn0o.png), while this is the original path [itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbiNI.png). The plot for the svg path was generated using [this](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) online tool.

Comment: Hi there! Can you, by any chance, post a link to the SVG you're using as an input?

Answer (score 0):

The function below should probably work:

```py
def sample_polygon(polygon, n_points):
    '''
    Generates a new shapely Polygon with a specific number of points sampled 
    from the original input.

    Parameters
    ----------
    polygon : shapely.geometry.Polygon
        The input polygon from which the points will be sampled
    n_points : integer
        The number of points to sample

    Returns
    -------
    sampled_poly : shapely.geometry.Polygon
        Newly-generated polygon. It will have as many points as the `n_points` 
        variable demands.

    '''
    # Sampling the coordinates
    sample_coords = [polygon
                     .exterior
                     .interpolate(i/n_points, 
                                  normalized=True) for i in range(n_points)]
    
    # Generating a new polygon
    sampled_poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon(sample_coords)
    
    return sampled_poly
```